# Accessing Protected Variable Of An Instance Of A Class That Extends An Abstract Base Class?

Tags: java, abstract, protected, access-modifiers, base-class

I have an abstract class called MyAction which contains a protected enum variable. The class is defined as follows:

```
package mypackage;

public abstract class MyAction {
    public enum ActionId {
        ACTION1, ACTION2;
    }

    protected ActionId actionId;

    // constructor
    public MyAction(ActionId actionId) {
        this.actionId = actionId;
    }

    public ActionId getActionId() {
        return actionId;
    }    
    ...
    ...
}
```

I created a specific action, MyAction1, that extends MyAction:

```
package mypackage;

public class MyAction1 extends MyAction {
    public MyAction1() {
        super(ActionId.ACTION1);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

I have a singleton utility class (in the same package) that creates an instance of MyAction1 and stores it in a HashMap:

```
package mypackage;

public class MyActionFactory {
    private static MyActionFactory theInstance;
    private HashMap<ActionId, MyAction> actions;

    private MyActionFactory() {
        actions = new HashMap<ActionId, MyAction>();
        MyAction1 myAction1 = new MyAction1();
        actions.put(myAction1.actionId, myAction1); // able to access protected variable actionId
    }

    public static VsActionFactory getInstance() {
        if (theInstance == null)
            theInstance = new VsActionFactory();
        return theInstance;
    }    
    ...
    ...
}
```

Note that in the method *actions.put(**myAction1.actionId**, myAction1)* I am able to access the protected member *actionId*.

Why is it that I can access the protected member *actionId* (contained in the base class *MyAction*) of the instance of *MyAction1*? I thought protected members were only accessible to subclasses.

Does it have anything to do with *MyActionFactory* being in the same package as the others?

Comment: Protected members are accessible in all classes of same package. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Oh. I thought it was only to subclasses. That was an easy answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `protected` keyword makes things visible within the same package. Which is the case, because both of your classes are in `package mypackage`.

Here is a nice table, taken from [Oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

[image]

Comment: Now I know that. I guess I could have tested it by moving the utility class to another package.

Comment: So there is no way of making a variable in the base class that's only accessible to subclasses and not to other classes in the same package?

Comment: No that is not possible.

Comment: I noticed something strange looking at your table. If you don't define a modifier then other classes can access it but not sub-classes (even if the sub-class is defined in the same package)?

Comment: The best way to sum it up is to see that each higher level of access fully encompasses lower levels: it's a strict hierarchy of expanding circles.

Comment: Good way to look at it!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Indeed. However, to me it feels like the level of package and subclass should be swapped around. What do you think?

Comment: You mean, swap the Package and Subclas *columns*, so that we get a modifier which allows *only* the subclasses in? The way it is works better for me: a package is a set of closely coupled classes, they are all "friends" in C++ terms. `protected`, on the other hand, is a form of public access, to be used in classes designed for public extension. It would make little sense to allow public extension, but preclude package-private access.

Comment: Oh, you are right! I was mixing up the concept inner class with subclass. When I saw the table and I was thinking of subclass as of a, innerclass, I was disappointed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Protected access modifier allows access in the same package + sub classes in other packages.You can remember it as default access plus inheritance.